# How to do ../ when using docker COPY

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to copy a `package.json` file inside my container with COPY, so I made

```
COPY package*.json .
```

This is working but now I'm trying to copy this `package.json` who is not in the same folder as the Dockerfile. So I tried:

```
COPY ../../package*.json .
```

and

```
COPY ./../../package*.json .
```

Without success.

How can I go back in folders when i'm trying to copy a file in a Dockerfile ? There is no infos to do something on the `COPY` command doc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible to `COPY` files from outside of the build context:

> The `<src>` path must be inside the context of the build; you cannot `COPY ../something /something`, because the first step of a docker build is to send the context directory (and subdirectories) to the docker daemon.
>   **source:** https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy

Comment: Usually this means the `Dockerfile` is at the root of your project source tree, but you could also run `docker build` from the root of the tree and reference `subdirectory/Dockerfile`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try use volumes instead. Then the command will look like this:

```
docker run -v `pwd`../path/:/app/path your_image
```

Comment: That won’t cause content to be in the image.